# Setting CMake variables in QtCreator

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

In the [Qt Creator 2.8 documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-project-cmake.html) *(now defunct, alternative link [here](https://qt.developpez.com/doc/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-cmake/))* there is a screenshot showing a wizard dialog where I can pass CMake command line arguments:

> The screenshot below shows how you can specify command line arguments to CMake for your project.
>
> [image: CMake Wizard screenshot]

Is there a way to make these settings not there, but in a `CMakeLists.txt` file?

For example, if I want a project to compile in release, every time I have to type `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` into this dialog. How can I set that I want the project to build in release mode in a `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QtCreator 4 and CMake parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599468/qtcreator-4-and-cmake-parameters)

Comment: Consider changing title as it is misleading: the question and answers are about setting CMake variables rather than passing command line arguments (switches) to cmake executable

Answer (score 4):

Before QtC 4 just pass it as string when you build the CMakeLists.txt.

Since QtC 4 `"Tools" > "Options" > "Build & Run" > "Your kit" > "CMake configuration"`

Add a line an rebuild. You can go the short way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> (Projects mode) > "Manage Kits...", too.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Qt Creator 4, you can set CMake configuration variables in the project settings as follows:

1. Open the "Projects" sidebar tab and there go to "Build & Run → (your build config) → Build → CMake".
2. In the table of CMake configuration settings, check if the variable you want to define already exists. If so, double-click on its value and change it.
3. If the variable does not yet exist, click <kbd>Add</kbd>, select the type, then add its name and value.

   If you need to assign multiple values to your variable, separate them with "`;`". That is equivalent to how CMake defines multi-value lists.
4. Click the button "Apply Configuration Changes" below the list.

While it is also possible to make these settings in your `CMakeLists.txt` makefile, that is better avoided for configuration settings specific to just your machine. That way, you can include the `CMakeLists.txt` into your source code repository because one version is suitable for all developers then.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments. Because cmake will cache the build type, you only need to set it when you change it. I use QtCreator on Linux with cmake and typically I either: 1) have separate build trees for a Release and Debug build, or 2) build everything as Release and then use Whitt's approach to set the build type to Debug for the few projects I need to interactively debug. When I have completely different build trees, I use QtCreator with the debug config, and then just use a terminal to build the release.

Answer (score -1):

SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release")

Try something like that in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Build type does not belong in your CMakeLists.txt file.